# Should Buddhists only cultivate native plants?

Tags: karma, ethics

Reading various threads here, I know that plants are not considered to be sentient beings in Buddhism. But I still can't help wondering whether Buddhists create bad karma if they cultivate non-native plants. By 'cultivate' I mean for example *planting* a palm tree in a temperate climate (with large temperature changes over a year) or a giant sequoia anywhere but in the Sierra Nevada mountains in California. (I do *not* mean caring for plants that have been planted by others before me.)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Buddhism SE. We have a [Guide](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/i-am-a-new-user-here-at-buddhism-se-what-should-i-know-before-i-post?cb=1) and a [Resource tab](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) for new users that you might like.

Answer (score 1):

Unwholesome actions are created when the *intention/volition* behind the action is unwholesome.

If one is cultivating plants with intentions of *greed, anger, non-harmlessness*, then one is creating unwholesome kamma, which will produce unwholesome future resultants.

If one is cultivating plants with wholesome intentions such as *good-will, caring, altruism*, wholesome future resultants will be produced.

What is important here, is the Mind that is behind the action. Everything starts in the Mind, with reference to [the twin verses in the Dhammapada](http://www.buddhanet.net/dhammapada/d_twin.htm).

[image]